# How to write multiple filenames as a row in dataframe

Tags: r, lidr

I am new to R. I am trying to apply a function to several files and write a dataframe which includes all the file names as one column and corresponding "roughness" result as another column.

```
library(lidR)
files <- list.files(path= "/allfiles", pattern= "*.laz", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)

O = lapply(files, function(x)) {

  las = readLAS(x, select = "xyzicnrRGB", filter = "keep_first -drop_z_below 0"),
  chm = grid_canopy(las, 0.2, p2r()),
  roughness <- rumple_index(chm),

  return(roughness)

}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there. You can use a dataframe. I don't have your file or the library lidR installed, so hopefully rumple_index doesn't return anything too cranky

```
library(lidR)
files <- list.files(path= "/allfiles", pattern= "*.laz", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)

O = lapply(files, function(x) {

  las = readLAS(x, select = "xyzicnrRGB", filter = "keep_first -drop_z_below 0")
  chm = grid_canopy(las, 0.2, p2r())
  roughness <- rumple_index(chm)
  return(data.frame(file=x,roughness=roughness))

})
O = do.call(rbind,O)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it returns `Error in data.frame(File = x, roughness = roughness) : 
  object 'x' not found`

Comment: Oh, there's a bug in your original code. I have edited mine now. Should work

Comment: Thanks, after removing commas at the end of each line in function, code is running but returning error. `Error in C_rasterize(las, layout, subcircle, 1L) : 
  C++ unexpected internal error in 'rasterize': point of raster.` For single file it works fine. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Oh yes, you don't need the comma. Sorry I don't have lidR installed or the files. The error is coming from your readLAS functions..  Maybe it doesn't work with one of your files

Comment: so you figured out the error of readLAS? and everything worked?